# Boost installation -Simplified Build From Source

Tags: c++, boost

As mentioned in the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-binaries-from-source)

what do i need to install to run the commands :

```
bootstrap
.\bjam
```

The BoostPro Computing folks maintain the Boost installer for Windows, but if I first run the installer and download a minimal build and then run the installer again, the installer doesn't detect that I've already installed Boost already and I need some more libraries. Is there a way around ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set up Your BOOST_ROOT environment variable first:

winXP:

```
set BOOST_ROOT=D:\your\boost\sources
```

then in the BOOST_ROOT directory run:

```
boostrap.bat
```

this will create your bjam.exe and it's environment.
Next step is to invoke:

```
bjam toolset=msvc stage
```

This will compile Your boost library and place all libs into the folder:

```
%BOOST_ROOT%\stage\lib
```

If you want to build everything use:

```
bjam toolset=msvc -a --build-type=complete stage
```

instead stage you can put install this will simply install this to lib.
During building there will be created huge directory bin.v2 with all object files.
Total installation is aprox: 1.5 GB for libs (shared+static+debug&release).

Comment: I want to maintain multiple versions of boost - 1.33 and 1.40 and also compile them for both VS 2005 and 2008. What is the toolset option for VS2008?

Comment: It was probably:
toolset=msvc-v90  / VS2008

But You could use appropriate vcvarsall.bat of your toolchain to solve that.

Comment: You do not actually need to set BOOST_ROOT -- bootstrap + bjam will work just fine. As for toolset option for VS2008, please refer to http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/reference/tools.html#bbv2.reference.tools.compiler.msvc -- it say you should use toolset=msvc-9.0. Finally, about 1.33 -- I am afraid you're in trouble. 1.33 is so old that it used old version of Boost.Build system and did not support msvc 9.0. It's best to read documentation that came with that version.

Comment: Yes, You don't need to have BOOST_ROOT, but I find it useful and good practice. Vladimir - nice to see You in this post (I'm the recent intel-win.jam issue guy.) Cheers P.

Answer (score 5):

I also found this [link](http://boost.teeks99.com/) in another post for boost binaries. Just downloading and its very helpful.  If anyone has tried this out and had issues, let us know

Comment: Yeah, I posted those because the BoostPro stuff always seemed out of date.  They also only download the ones you need, which can be good for some people since the entire unpacked set of windows libraries is HUGE.  Packed up though, the files aren't that bad (~140MB download).

Comment: the structure is this boost build is different for structure when built from original source code. this makes the cmake to fail due to "headers not found".